# Deployment issue with Dokku

Tags: python, tornado, dokku

I'm sorry if this issue has already been dealt with in the past, but I have scoured the net and have failed to turn up any fixes.

My issue is as follows:

I deployed a Tornado Python app with Dokku yesterday and all was gravy. I am working on this as a group project, however, so I had to wait for my changes to be merged with the master branch in our repository before I could push the most up-to-date app.py file to the server. Everything was fine, and then I pushed the updates and the app broke!

I have searched the net and thoroughly read the Dokku docs, but the problem persists. I have run dokku apps:destroy, removed the remote and started from scratch a dozen times and each time I deploy, as seen below:

[successful deployment screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9QVK.png)

At first I was greeted with a blue screen, but now on my most recent deployment I am getting sent to another one of my sites: https://hobby.logancodes.com/
**--edit-- the correct address should be http:mind-cloud.logancodes.com**
I'm not sure if the issue is my DNS setting, or something else but it's got me stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: always look in the log file.  Hint 2: "the app broke" is not sufficient evidence for someone else to understand your problem,  Hint 3: if you suspect it is a DNS problem, check what the DNS names resolve to and compare with the IP of the server / load balancer / whatever

Comment: I understand that it's not a lot to go on, but I'm sure this has happened to others. I've checked and re-checked the DNS, and I've tried to check the logs but I'm getting an error message:

Comment: dokku logs mind-cloud --tail
error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: EOF

Comment: I'm also currently back to just the blue screen

Comment: *Update*  It’s a problem with docker not cleaning up after itself. I fixed issue by running the following command: dokku ps:rebuildall